# How can I compare a string using or ||...

Tags: java, string, while-loop, operators

//I need the while loop to break when the user types y OR n.. but so far I can only get it for one letter/string.

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = user_input.next();
System.out.print("Would you like to order some coffee, "+name+"? (y/n)");
String coffeeYorN = user_input.next();

  while (!coffeeYorN.equals("y")||!coffeeYorN.equals"n")  //HERE IS MY ISSUE
  {
    System.out.println("Invalid response, try again.");
    System.out.print("Would you like to order some coffee, "+name+"? (y/n)");
     coffeeYorN = user_input.next();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the conditional is true, execute this loop.

Let's say someone enters "n"...

Your conditional says:

`Is the input something other than "y"? Yes, it is "n", so I should execute the loop.`

You need something like this: `while(!coffeeYorN.equals("y") && !coffeeYorN.equals("n"))`

Comment: Console input is not converted to char from string. You're checking for char.

Answer (score 2):

> I need the while loop to break when the user types y OR n

Then your condition should be:

```
while (!coffeeYorN.equals("y") && !coffeeYorN.equals("n"))
```

Or the equivalent, but a bit clearer version, which I think is what you wanted to do:

```
while (!(coffeeYorN.equals("y") || coffeeYorN.equals("n")))
```

Let's check the truth table:

```
Y - coffeeYorN.equals("y")
N - coffeeYorN.equals("n")

case   Y N  (!Y || !N)  !(Y || N)
  0    0 0      1           1
  1    0 1      1           0
  2    1 0      1           0
  3    1 1      0           0
```

You want the condition to evaluate to `true` and the loop to keep going only in case `0`, when neither `Y` or `N` are true, and stop for all the other cases. The way you did it, it will stop only if `coffeeYorN` is equal to `"y"` and `"n"` at the same time (case `3`), which can never happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I can't find it.

Your if statement says "if it's not y or n", which will always be true, because something can't be "y" and "n" at the same time.

You want to use "and", rather than "or".